# wrong result when find the number of digit inside a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, fseek

Here is the situation:

First, The input consists of the number of test cases, `m`, in the first line and followed by `m` test cases. Each test case consists of a string with less than 256 characters. The String may contain "Space bar". My Programming language is C.

Then, here is my problem. I cannot find any problem in my code and I can perfectly run the example with correct result. However, when I upload it onto online judgement system, it shows "WA(Wrong Answer)".

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int numberOfDigit(char input[255])
{
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (input[i] >= 48 && input[i] <= 57)
            num++;
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfTestCase;
    char input[255];
    int digit[9999];

    scanf("%d", &numberOfTestCase);

    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTestCase; j++) {
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
        gets(input);
        digit[j] = numberOfDigit(input);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numberOfTestCase; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", digit[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

I want to explain something in my process of coding.

Because the input contains space character, I use `gets()` function so that I can get a string without stopping by typing space.
However, if I don't add `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);`, `gets()` only appears `numberOfTestCase-1` times, I asked on stackOverflow, and was advised that `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);` can solve the problem, which I don't know why. But when I add it, the problem is solved, but it fails tests in the online judgement system.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Don't use `gets`, it's dangerous. It has also been deprecated since the C99 standard, and removed in the C11 standard. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: So, I change it into fgets(input, 256, stdin);

Comment: But Any Problem now? I only left 3 chance to hands it onto the judge system.

Comment: You need to find out why it fails the online judge system. I suggest that you start by creating some test cases of your own. Choose some inputs and determine the expected output from your `numberOfDigit()` function. Start with simple test cases. The goal is to find the test cases that causes your code to fail the online judge.

Comment: Your buffer size is too short. If a string may have up to 255 non-zero characters, you need to have at least 256-byte buffer to store it with the ending zero.

Comment: Don't hardcode ASCII codepoints. Use `isdigit()`.

Comment: How do you run it locally? In automated tests it is most probably just fed some file into input and may have `EOF` in place of the last `\n`

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` would stop reading input if it sees a newline. Also fseek() may not work on stdin and it's unnecessary for your purpose. Instead you can `fgets()` to read the first line too instead of `scanf()`. And then you can use [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) to read the input number.

Something like:

```
fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
sscanf(input, "%d", &numberOfTestCase);

for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTestCase; j++) {
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    digit[j] = numberOfDigit(input);
}

for (int k = 0; k < numberOfTestCase; k++) {
    printf("%d\n", digit[k]);
}
```

You can also use the chracter constants instead of hard-coding ASCII values, which is more readable and portable:

```
for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')
        num++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the right answer. I never think about using fgets to read the first line instead of scanf. I learn from it a lot. Thanks.